# PhpStorm in Ubuntu can't detect pd_dump executable on PostgreSQL Export

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, phpstorm, pg-dump, datagrip

##### My environment:

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on Windows 10
-> https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6

PhpStorm 2022.1 Build #PS-221.5080.224, built on April 13, 2022

##### My Problem:

I'm trying to export a PostgreSQL database inside the Database tab of PhpStorm.

To execute the export I right click the database in the list and click on the "Export with 'pg_dump'" option. This opens the Export window with all the options and command preview:

[image: Screenshot of the export window with error message]

Inside of the window I get the error message "Path to executable is wrong" even tho the pg_dump file exists at the given path `/usr/bin/pg_dump`. This stops me from executing the export.

I have tried to manually install pg_dump in another directory and select it in the PhpStorm Export window, but it still won't detect the executable. The executable itself works fine.

Comment: Just to clarify your setup: you are running PhpStorm inside WSL2, right? So it's a Linux-run PhpStorm? Or it's a Windows-based PhpStorm but you have PostgreSQL installed in WSL2 and running that WSL-based `pg_dump`?

Comment: Yes exactly, i'm running PhpStorm inside of WSL2.

Comment: Also for clarification I'm accessing the PhpStorm display with a MobaXterm X-Server on Windows. So everything actually runs inside of WSL2 linux and i'm accessing it remotely via windows.

Comment: I'm not really a Linux user (rather limited Linux experience) but overall your setup should work just fine. **1)** Could be access permissions but that's unlikely IMO. But double check what user is used to run PhpStorm/what it can access. **2)** **Most importantly:** how did you install PhpStorm? Was it Flatpack or alike? That can be an issue as in such a case PhpStorm content will be "virtualized" and may not have access to other apps on your system (unless manually adjusted in the "manifest"). Can you check on this?

Comment: So i've checked the access permissions. PhpStorm was running via my own user and the pg_dump file was owned by the root user. I've tried running PhpStorm with the root user but PhpStorm still wasnt able to access the pg_dump file.

Comment: The way i installed PhpStorm was downloading the zip file from the https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=linux website and just extracting that inside of the linux filesystem via "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\" in a windows explorer window. To start PhpStorm i just execute the "phpstorm.sh" file in the "bin" folder either with the Ubuntu command line or with a custom Shell file in my home directory that just does the same command "sh /path/to/phpstorm.sh" so i dont have to type the path every time

Comment: If it was installed from ZIP then it's fine as it's not a "virtualisation" kind of issue. Sadly cannot say what else it might be. No ideas except "try rebooting your OS; this magic is not Windows only solution". You will have to wait for somebody else with much better Linux experience to see and comment here. **P.S.**You can always use ` Help | Contact Support...` in PhpStorm to contact PhpStorm Support Team with your issue.

Comment: This problem has been going on for a long time for me. A reboot sadly won't help. I'll try to get help from the support and post the solution to it here if there is one. Thank you very much for your help tho :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to do a `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client`.

Apparently there is a general problem with the pg_dump executable of the "postgresql-client-common" package:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/501091/command-pg-dump-not-found

After installing the postgresql-client package, everything works fine in PhpStorm as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty simple there: IDE checks that file exists and is executable, then run `/path/to/pg_dump --version` command and parse output looking for some keywords. Unfortunately there are no logs which can show exact reason, but I guess the issue that IDE can't get access to the file. Most likely due to WSL. The workaround is to install IDE and unpack PG binaries on Windows, then configure port forwarding to make PG server accessible from host OS.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sadly due to company policy i have to work inside of the WSL and can't switch over to Windows. I did however find the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please run:

```
which mysqldump
```

or

```
where mysqldump
```

and change the path to the resulting output of the above commands, worked for me.